# PHP - Link from Folder

Tags: php, list, hyperlink, directory

I'm currently working on the front-end of a clients website.
He's a photographer and doesnt want to bother with CMS systems (sheesh).

I'll just explain it the way he explained it to me:

He wants to create folders on his FTP filled with images.
These folders represent the pages or categories.
The images inside these folders should then be displayed on the page created from the folder.
If the folder is named "fashion", he wants the domain to read: www.client.com/fashion.

I was looking all over the internet for a solution, and i really hope you can help me out of my misery.

Basicly, i need a tuned down directory listing system that scans for folders and creates links inside a php file with the folders name, displaying the images inside. Also, if you drop a txt file in the folder, it should display the text inside it.

This system is similar to the Stacey CMS, but sadly he doesnt want any CMS.

If you need any more information, dont hesitate to drop a message.

Thank you.

Comment: So he wants you to write a system to manage his content, but he doesn't want a content management system? Sounds like some re-education is needed.

Comment: What is is asking for **is** a CMS. Just file the end off Stacey's name.

Comment: I know guys, he's the comlicated type :/

Comment: you want logic the traverse a PHP folder and display folder content ?

Comment: The complicated types make terrible clients. Either you need to A) find out what part of his requirements he is not making clear, or B) re-educate him on what a CMS is, or C) walk away. Any other solution will lead to massive headaches.

Comment: @Mike, it will undoubtedly be more than that. If he wants to be able to drop in text files to be displayed, he will later ask for control over the formatting. If he wants images displayed, he will later ask for captions. It is never as simple as traversing a directory, because that doesn't produce a good website.

Comment: @George Cummins Just make sure you get paid by the hour ;-)

Comment: @jeroen: That's a way to protect the developer, but what about the poor client? He is getting a custom-built CMS with limited features when existing products will do exactly what he wants. He will pay extra for an inferior product, which will lead to hard feelings. Nobody benefits from that.

Comment: @George Cummins If there already is a system that does what he wants, just use that and don't call it a CMS; if a client doesn't want to be bothered with technical terms, don't use them. Everybody benefits if you do it right :-)

Comment: I'm already over the headache part. Since my knowledge with php is close to zero, it's getting more complicated by the minute.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to rewrite the URL so it is passed to your PHP script so you can do something with it. Assuming Apache, you would place something like this is a .htaccess file:

Ref: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ imagelist.php?dir=$1 [L]
```

Then, in `imagelist.php`, do something like the following:

```
<?php

  $baseDir = 'images/';

  $workingDir = $baseDir.$_GET['dir'];

  if (!is_dir($workingDir) || (!$dp = opendir($workingDir))) {
    exit('Unknown category: '.$_GET['dir']);
  }

  echo '<html><head><title>'.$_GET['dir'].'</title></head></body>';

  while (($file = readdir($dp)) !== FALSE) {
    if (substr(strtolower($file),-4) == '.txt') {
      // Handle text files
      echo '<pre>'.file_get_contents($workingDir.'/'.$file).'<pre>';
    } else {
      // Treat everything else as an image
      echo '<img src="'.$workingDir.'/'.$file.'" alt="'.$file.'" title="'.$file.'">';
    }
  }

  echo '</body></html>';
```

Obviously this doesn't do any nice formatting of the layout, but hopefully it will give you a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is this,

1. Read category from url (use mod_rewrite for this)

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

   # Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
   ```
2. Scan the directory you read on step 1 by php.
3. Show the contents in a nice html template
4. For a single photo (if you want to show it in full screen) use another template.

It'd require 2 php scripts. And 2 html templates. Additionally you may need a solution for thumbnail creation.

Comment: Intentionally didn't give any code snipped. Not even for upvote. Giving snippet for such task will be coding for OP. But if OP searches every step in google he will get a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple actually. Use the DirectoryIterator. I'll post some code to give you a push in the right direction but I am not giving you the solution, you have to do that yourself ;-)

I use this snippet to fetch a list of the folders in my banners directory:

```
    $tmpDir = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'banners'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'emrc'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $dirProc=new DirectoryIterator($tmpDir);
    $banerSizes = array();
    foreach($dirProc as $dirContent){
        if ($dirContent->isFile() || substr($dirContent->getFilename(), 0, 1) === '.') continue;
        if ($dirContent->isDir()) {
            $banerSizes[] = $dirContent->getFilename();
        }
    }
    natcasesort($banerSizes);
```

I use this to display them: (note: I do not link the image but I do supply a code sample to copy and paste the link. This can easily be modified to your needs)

```
    <table class="regular" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <?php 
        /**
         * Display bannes
         */
        foreach($banerSizes as $bannerSize){
            $tmpDir = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'banners'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'emrc'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$bannerSize.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
            $dirProc=new DirectoryIterator($tmpDir);
            ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a name="<?php echo $bannerSize; ?>"><?php echo $bannerSize; ?></a>
                <hr />
            </td>
        </tr>

            <?php 
            foreach($dirProc as $dirContent){
                if (!$dirContent->isFile() || substr($dirContent->getFilename(), 0, 1) === '.') continue;
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <img src="/banners/emrc/<?php echo $bannerSize; ?>/<?php echo $dirContent->getFilename(); ?>" />
                <br />
                <textarea cols="42" rows="4" readonly="readyonly"><a href="<?php echo $affiliateLink; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $siteLink; ?>/banners/emrc/<?php echo $bannerSize; ?>/<?php echo $dirContent->getFilename(); ?>" /></a></textarea>
                <br />
                <hr style="width:384px" />                      
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
            }
        }
        ?>              
    </table>
```

Don't use tables. I only did because it was required for the template I worked in.
I hope this helps you, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Of course i dont use tables, i'm a front-end developer, thus i'm not really into php, so i cant really think of a solution myself.